# How can I update a toggle switch in SwiftUI and store its state in Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to sync the state of a toggle button with Firestore, but I don't have enough knowledge to implement it yet. This button is used to add and remove items from a favorites list. The favorites list itself is already syncing with Firestore, but I'm facing an issue with keeping the toggle button's state in sync.

I'm currently using UserDefaults for temporary storage, but I understand it's not an ideal solution.

ViewModel:

```
@Published var favoriteItem: Set<String> {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Array(favoriteItem), forKey: "favoriteItem")
        }
    }

    init() {
        // Retrieve favorite items from UserDefaults
        if let storedFavorites = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "favoriteItem") as? [String] {
            favoriteItem = Set(storedFavorites)
        } else {
            favoriteItem = []
        }
    }

    func isUserFavorite(itemId: String) -> Bool {
        return favoriteItem.contains(itemId)
    }

    func toggleFavorite(itemId: String) {
        if isUserFavorite(itemId: itemId) {
            // Remove
            favoriteItem.remove(itemId)
            removeUserFavoriteItem(favoriteItemId: itemId)
            
        } else {
            // Add
            favoriteItem.insert(itemId)
            addUserFavoriteItem(itemId: itemId)
        }
    }
```

View:

```
private var favoriteButton: some View {
    Button {
        viewModel.toggleFavorite(itemId: itemId)
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: viewModel.isUserFavorite(itemId: itemId) ? "bookmark.fill" : "bookmark")
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven’t provided any of your list code. We would need to know how all this connects to what you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved that.

```
func isUserFavoriteItem(itemId: String) -> Bool {
        // this array reed data from firestore rather than UserDefault
        return FavoriteItem.contains { $0. itemId == itemId }
    }
```